# How to extract value from dictionary into new colum?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains one column with format like {"orderNum":123456}
Here is the example:

```
ActionTime           Details            OrderNumber
0   1/2/2021 17:21  {"orderNum":123456} 
1   1/2/2021 20:16  {"orderNum":467899} 
2   1/3/2021 8:38   {"orderNum":753951}
```

And here is what i have tried:

```
    df['OrderNumber'] = df[['Details','"orderNum"']].apply(lambda col: 
    col.explode()).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.head()
```

All what i need to is extract the order number from Details and put it into OrderNumber column.
How do i do this?

Comment: What's the dtype of the Details column? Is it a string?

Comment: It is an object type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Details` column is a string representation of a dictionary, you could use regular expressions to extract the number:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Action": [0, 1, 2], "Details": ['{"orderNum":123456}', '{"orderNum":467899}', '{"orderNum":753951}']})

df['OrderNumber'] = df['Details'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
```

gives

```
   Action              Details  OrderNumber
0       0  {"orderNum":123456}       123456
1       1  {"orderNum":467899}       467899
2       2  {"orderNum":753951}       753951
```

Comment: thant worked like a charm. I think i was overcomplicating trying to do it with lambda function. Thank you so much.

Comment: you could even do `df['Details'].str['orderNum']`, assuming it is a dictionary

Comment: @sammywemmy that's why I asked for the datatype. But since "object" can be either string or dict, I decided to play it safe. Your solution is more elegant though.

Comment: my apologies; I wasn't criticising

Comment: @sammywemmy nothing to worry!